# How to remove all the files in a directory?

Tags: linux, directory, rm, recursive

I am trying to remove all files and subdirectories in a directory. I used `rm -r` to remove all files, but I want to remove all files *and* subdirectories, excluding the top directory itself.

For example, I have a top directory like `images`. It contains the files `header.png`, `footer.png` and a subdirectory.

Now I want to delete `header.png`, `footer.png` and the subdirectory, but not `images`.

How can I do this in linux?

Comment: cd into the directory and do an `rm -Rf` of all the files and directories in there.

Answer (score 71):

If your top-level directory is called `images`, then run `rm -r images/*`. This uses the shell glob operator `*` to run `rm -r` on every file or directory within `images`.

Comment: hidden file will not be deleted.

Answer (score 63):

To delete hidden files, you have to specify:

```
rm -r images/* images/.*
```

With shells whose globs include `.` and `..`, this will lead to an error like

```
rm: cannot remove `.' directory `images/.'
rm: cannot remove `..' directory `images/..'
```

but it will delete hidden files.

An approach without errormessage is to use find/delete with mindepth. This is gnu-find.

```
find images -mindepth 1 -delete
```

Your find may lack the `-mindepth` or `-delete` predicate, in which case, you could do:

```
find images/. ! -name . -prune -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Comment: My suggestion was to use 'rm -r images/.*' which would match 'images/..' but not 'images/../..'. The recursion can't go upwards, since 'images/../images/..'  is again the same directory.

Comment: @DarkHeart `rm .*` doesn't delete `.` or `..` and [hasn't since at least 1994 for the GNU utils and likely since the late 70s for UNIX](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90075/22222). It is extremely unlikely you'll find a system where `rm .*` traverses the filesystem upwards outside of a museum.

Answer (score 22):

To delete all files and directories(including the **hidden** ones) in a directory, you can try the following:

- use `ls -Ab` to match all files/directories

  ```
  cd dir_name && rm -rf `ls -Ab`
  ```
- use `find` to match all files/directories

  ```
  find dir_name -mindepth 1 -delete
  ```

  or, if your `find` doesn't support `-delete`:

  ```
  find dir_name -mindepth 1 -exec rm -rf {}
  ```
- delete the folder, then recreate it

  ```
  rm -rf dir_name && mkdir dir_name
  ```
- in bash,

  ```
  shopt -s dotglob  
  rm -rf dir_name/*
  ```

Comment: Note that command like `rm -rf *` is not safe if you have no knowledge of files in a directory, because a file starting with `-` (hyphen) will be interpreted as `rm` flag...

Comment: EDIT: to do it safe, use `rm -rf ./* ./.*`

Answer (score 15):

To delete all *regular* files recursively inside a directory, this command (assuming GNU or FreeBSD `find`) is good enough:

```
find . -type f -delete
```

That leaves all the non-regular files like symlinks (whether they point to regular files or not), directories, fifos, sockets, devices...

See also:

```
find . ! -type d -delete
```

to delete files of any type except *directory*.

Answer (score 6):

Try this version:

```
 rm -r test/*
```

Comment: This won't remove hidden files (ones starting with ".").

Answer (score 4):

The question was to empty a directory = remove contents of a directory including hidden files, but not the directory itself.
The find command with -mindepth 1 is actually the correct way to go, but to avoid error messages it must be joined with -maxdepth 1:

```
find /path/to/dir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using `find` command here:

**Step 1:** Find all the files and delete them :

```
find /path/to/directory/ -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Example:

```
find /home/user/Desktop/images/ -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

**Step 2:** Find all the sub-directories and delete them :

```
find /path/to/directory/ -type d -exec rm -R {} \;
```

Comment: `find /path/to/directory/ -type d` includes `.` so will delete the directory itself. You need to also use the `-mindepth` switch as others have said.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
$ rm -rf /path/to/directory/{*,.*}
```

source: https://askubuntu.com/a/552834/56648

Answer (score 0):

rm's syntax is:

```
rm [OPTION]... FILE...
```

So, you have to state the appropriate path explicitly, e.g.

```
rm -r sub_dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove directory using following command:

```
sudo rm -r directoryname1/2/3/*
```

It will be delete entire directory after 3/*.

Example 
      sudo rm -r Downloads/song/*

It will be delete all files which are within `Downloads/song`.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me, tested several variations worked every time.

From the directory that holds the images directory.

```
rm -frd ./images/*
```

before:

```
images/
    |_ header.png
    |_ footer.png
    |_ subdir/
```

after:

```
images/
```

Comment: Not sure it was made clear in the original question, but just to point out that unless you enable dotglob, this will skip any "dot-file" or dot-directory under images (`mkdir images/.somedir`; `touch images/.somefile`)

Answer (score 0):

To delete all files and subdirectories in the current directory, **including hidden ones, without error message**:

```
rm -rf .[^.] .??* *
```

Or, from the parent directory:

```
rm -rf images/.[^.] images/.??* images/*
```

From https://serverfault.com/a/47940/269538.

Answer (score -2):

Delete the folder "test" and all the files inside:

```
 rm -r test
```

Delete all the files inside but keep the folder "test":

```
 rm -r test/*
```

Answer (score -4):

cd into the folder then execute the following command:

```
ls |xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: This will fail in on filenames that contain whitespace. I would recommend against using the output of ls as input to other commands, it is generally unsafe.