# What do lines such as "-y" or "-r" placed in the CLI do?

Tags: linux

What do lines such as "-y" or "-r" placed in the CLI do? I am learning Linux from the ground up (sort of) and want a solid understanding of what I'm typing into the Terminal. I have been looking up ways to customize and retrieve/install things and have found things like "tar -tvf" or "yum -y" followed by a program or file. Any clarity on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Those are options to the commands like `tar` or `yum`. They are very command-dependent, even though a few ones can be somewhat standard (such as `-h` that often gives you some help about the command).

Comment: the `r` could mean recursive (tar, zip, ...), the `y` assume-yes (apt, yum). There is no general rule, you'ld rather check for the man pages of your commands.

Comment: Thank you all! This is exactly what I needed to get started. I appreciate the quick responses!

Comment: if `man [command]` doesn't find anything try `[command] -h` or `[command] --help`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very simple, these are command parameters (aka options or flags). It is convention that they start with minus, but one minus can be followed by several options. `ls` means list; `ls -a` means **list all**, that is including hidden files. `ls -l` means **list in long format**. Consequently `ls -la` means **list all in long format**. For `rm` - the remove command `rm -r` can be a dangerous option as it means remove (delete) recursively - so if you are root you could delete the entire filesystem if you are not paying attention with `rm -rf *`[as described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106024/does-rm-rf-delete-files-recursively-from-the-current-directory-or-parent-root). For every command specifics can be found in manpages such as `man ls`. You get used to reading those and quickly find specifics with `/` to find inside a manpage, then `n` will seek next occurrence of the search string. Exit manpage with `q` for quit. Also many commands and their examples you can search for with Google - just surround the search with quotes if it includes whitespace. One of the first things you can learn about is chaining (properly called **piping**) - how output from one command goes into the next separated​ by `|` the pipe symbol. Then it all starts to make much sense. A good place for various examples is [bashOneLiners](http://www.bashoneliners.com/). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Wish I could upvote with my small rep. This is just what a noobie needed to get started. Much appreciated!

Comment: It's ok. If it helps you can just accept. Also do not hesitate to ask more and experiment. People will be happy to help.