# Why doesn't recursion go upwards with rm?

Tags: recursive

I'm wondering about direction of recursion in general and rm specifically.

rm recursion only works downwards correct?

Running:  `sudo rm -R *.QTFS` will delete all *.QTFS files in current directory and its children, correct?

current directory as displayed by `ls -lha` also contains `.` and `..` links for the lack of a better word, so why doesn't recursion follow these upwards in the directory tree? Is there an artificial limit on rm app, or `.` and `..` are not real things?

Comment: Because root, and madness, that way lies...

Comment: Related: [Does 'rm .*' ever delete the parent directory?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90073/22565)

Comment: Well, for an interesting anecdote...  I ran rm -rf on some innocent looking subdirectories at one point only to find to my horror that a user had hard linked stuff in there to a very important upstream, which rm then proceeded to eat.  Yeah, I had current backups and no data was lost, but let it be a cautionary tale...  :-)

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch, what harm could be done by removing a hard link? I didn't get the point of you story...

Comment: @Alexey The point is that the hard link itself was not removed.  It recursed down into the hard linked directory, which was linked to a higher point in the filesystem, so started eating everyone's data...

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch, but i do not believe someone could [hardlink a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22394).

Comment: @Alexey That particular version of Solaris definitely did allow it.  I know.  I had to recover the data that got wiped out...

Comment: I understand now, thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> `rm` recursion only works downwards correct?

`rm -r x y` will delete `x` and `y` and everything inside them (if they are directories), but not their parents or anything outside them.

> Running: `sudo rm -R *.QTFS` will delete all *.QTFS files in current directory and its children, correct?

No. It will delete all files named `*.QTFS`, any files recursively inside *directories* called `*.QTFS`, and those directories themselves. If you want that other deletion behaviour, use [`find -delete`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).

> current directory as displayed by `ls -lha` also contains `.` and `..` links for the lack of a better word, so why doesn't recursion follow these upwards in the directory tree? Is there an artificial limit on rm app, or `.` and `..` are not real things?

It's an artificial limit of `rm`.

It's not really all that artificial, though - it's the only way it could ever work. If `rm` followed the parent `..` links, every `rm -r` would remove every file on the system, by following all of the `..` links all the way back to `/`. `rm` sees the `..` and `.` entries in each directory when it [lists](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html) the content, and explicitly disregards them for that reason.

You can try that out yourself, in fact. Run `rm -r .` and most `rm` implementations will refuse to act, reporting an error explicitly:

```
$ rm -r .
rm: refusing to remove ‘.’ or ‘..’ directory: skipping ‘.’
```

(that message [is from GNU `rm`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/remove.c;h=4cc4a0817645c6716f90ba1c6c046f192f45b350;hb=HEAD#l441); others are similar). When it encounters these entries implicitly, rather than as explicit arguments, it just ignores them and continues on. That behaviour is [required by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html). In GNU `rm` and many of the BSDs, it's provided automatically by the [`fts_read`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fts_read) family of hierarchy-traversal functions.

> or `.` and `..` are not real things?

`.` and `..` are *generally* real directory entries, although that is filesystem-specific. They will almost always be presented as though they are real entries to all user code, regardless. Many pieces of software (not just `rm`) special-case their behaviour in order to catch or prevent runaway or undesirable recursion.

Comment: For anyone seeking proof (or just plain interested), take a look at [how this is implemented in GNU coreutils](http://lingrok.org/xref/coreutils/src/remove.c#438).

Comment: @ChrisHayes The equivalent gitweb link is in the answer. The actual recursive case is in the `fts_read` implementation, though, that one is just for command-line arguments.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Oh wow, so it is. That link color does *not* stand out on this SE scheme. My mistake.

Comment: This answer is correct but also a little imprecise. `rm` doesn't even see `*.QTFS` because it's glob-expanded into the filenames by bash before the rm binary is invoked. @tobyink's answer notes that.

Comment: As a sidenote, those `.` and `..` special-case behaviour are said to be [the cause of the dotfiles existence](https://plus.google.com/+RobPikeTheHuman/posts/R58WgWwN9jp)

Comment: Be carefull here. Some older UNIX systems (some early bsd's, Ultrix) will go upstream if you do "rm -rf .*". Told  a colleague of mine that back in the 90's and he wouldn't believe me. Lucky for him it was a decommissioned system that was going to be scrapped anyway.

Answer (score 5):

As well as what Michael Homer wrote there's another factor that makes it hard to accidentally recurse into the parent directory.

Go into your home directory and type something like:

```
echo *s*
```

You'll see that it shows a list of files and directories containing the letter "s". However, no files beginning with a leading dot are shown. To show them, you can use:

```
echo .*s*
```

This is because the shell refuses to expand `*` to encompass a leading dot. This means that:

```
rm -fr *
```

Will not recurse into `..`.