# `command .*` acts on the parent directory

Tags: bash, shell, directory, wildcards, dot-files

Someone of our team wanted to recursively change the user permissions on all hidden directories in a users home directory. To do so he executed the following command:

```
cd /home/username
chown -R username:groupname .*
```

We were pretty surprised when we realized, that he actually recursively changed the permissions of all user directories in /home, because `.*` equals to `..` as well. Would you have expected this behavior in Linux though?

Comment: `./.*` will include `./.` and `./..`, which is why you get that evil recursivity covering your entire system in the first place.

Comment: so `./.*` would have been ending up in the same disaster, if I got you right?

Comment: Have a look at `ls -d ./.*`. It includes `..`, the parent directory. And this directory would include its parent as well, and so on... Run `ls --recursive ./.*` and you'll see it...

Comment: You are right John, in this case I am going to edit my initial question and remove the wrong conclusion we made. Thank you...

Comment: Related: [Does 'rm .*' ever delete the parent directory?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90073/23408) `rm` specifically protects against this; commands like `chmod` and `chown` do not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I always get burned when I try using .* for anything and long ago switched to using character classes:

```
chown -R username.groupname .[A-Za-z]*
```

is how I would have done this.

Edit: someone pointed out that this doesn't get, for example dot files such as `._Library`.  The catch all character class to use would be

```
chown -R username.groupname .[A-Za-z0-9_-]*
```

Comment: Another more common alternative: `.??*` This will include digits and other signs which may end up in file names :)

Comment: `.??*` misses any single character name dot files; e.g. `.a`.  Admittedly such would be unlikely to exist, but it's worth pointing out.

Comment: Why not just use `.[^.]*`?

Comment: This doesn't get files with names like `.....`.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Does POSIX let you get away with that? I remember POSIX regex is different from regular regex.

Comment: @trlkly [Looks like a yes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)

Comment: @trlkly: 1. POSIX regexes *are* different from (say) Perl-style ones. 2. But `[^.]` does have the appropriate meaning in a POSIX regex. 3. But POSIX filename-expansion doesn't use the same rules as POSIX regex. (If it did, then `.*` would mean "zero or more characters" rather than "a dot, plus zero or more characters".) 4. And in POSIX filename-expansion, you have to write `[!` rather than `[^` -- the meaning of the latter is unspecified. 5. But the question specifically calls out Bash, not a generic POSIX shell, and Bash filename-expansion *does* support `[^` as equivalent to `[!`.

Comment: @Izkata: Not exactly. It's complicated. See my comment. (Or alternatively, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13_01: "the exclamation mark character (`'!'`) shall replace the circumflex character (`'^'`) in its role in a 'non-matching list'".)

Comment: @ruakh: The syntax used in pathname expansion is usually called `glob` as it is significantly different from most things called `regex`.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yup, I'm aware. (Hence `extglob`, `globstar`, etc.) But the specs don't seem to use that term; they just say "filename expansion", so that's what I stuck with in my comment. (By the end of #5, I was really nearing the character limit -- no room for any unnecessary facts. :-P )

Comment: This is the practical answer for interactive use, but doesn't handle the general case with unusual names (see @gilles answer below for that).  The edit to add 0-9, etc was unnecessary: to use this technique you always need to make sure (visually) that you're handling all the actual file names that exist in your particular situation.  This method shouldn't be used for a programmatic solution.

Answer (score 10):

Using the extended globbing (`shopt -s extglob`), you can use

```
.!(.|)
```

i.e. dot not followed by dot or nothing.

Answer (score 10):

The character `.` is only excluded from wildcard matching when it's the first character of the file name and it would be matched by a wildcard. In the pattern `.*`, the `*` matches strings beginning with `.`, so `.*` includes `..` (as well as `.`, with `*` matching the empty string). This is a straightforward consequence of the pattern matching rules, annoying though it may be.

It would make sense to make an exception and to systematically exclude `.` and `..` from matches, but that's not how it was done historically, so many Bourne/POSIX shells (`sh`, `dash`, `bash`, AT&T `ksh`, `yash` …) include them, as do (t)csh and even fish 1.x. A few shells exclude `.` and `..` from all wildcard matches: zsh, pdksh/posh/mksh (unlike AT&T ksh), fish [≥2.0](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/270).

If you set `GLOBIGNORE` to any non-empty value, **bash** switches to the convenient but non-standard behavior of excluding `.` and `..` from matches. Setting `GLOBIGNORE` also turns off the behavior of excluding dot files; with `GLOBIGNORE='.*'`, you get the usual behavior of `./*` excluding dot files, but `./.*` matches only dot files and not `.` or `..`. Set `GLOBIGNORE=.:..` (or `GLOBIGNORE=.`) to have `./*` match all files, including dot files, but excluding `.` and `..`.

In ksh93, set `FIGNORE='@(.|..)'` to exclude `.` and `..` from matches but include dot files. Thus `.*` will expand to dot files but not include `.` or `..`.

Without resorting to shell-specific features, you can match dot files with the following two globs:

```
.[!.]* ..?*
```

and all files (excluding `.` and `..`) with the following three globs:

```
..?* .[!.]* *
```

But you need to take care because one or several of the globs might not match any file, which would cause the corresponding pattern to remain unexpanded.

To avoid surprises, it might be easier to use `find`. `find` never recurses to the parent directory (unless told to follow symbolic links).

```
find /home/username/. -name . -o -prune -name '.*' -exec chown -R username:groupname {} +
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. Fish shell since 2.0 [doesn't include `.` and `..` in `.*`](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/270). If it does include them, it's a bug, and should be reported.

Comment: @xfix I'd checked with fish 1.23.1. I wasn't aware that the behavior had changed, thanks.

Comment: FWIW, the shorter and (IMO) slightly easier-to-understand `.[!.] .??*` can be used instead of `.[!.]* ..?*`.  Analysis of these glob patterns (all of them start with a single dot and do not match `.` or `..`): `.[!.]` = exactly 2 chars, 2nd is non-dot; `.??*` = 3+ chars; `.[!.]*` = 2+ chars, 2nd char is non-dot; `..?*` = 3+ chars, 2nd char is dot.

Answer (score 6):

Consider using `find` (`-maxdepth` is a non-POSIX extension, but it should be readily available on Linux):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '.*' -exec chown -R user:group {} +
```

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the cleanest solution, although not the shortest.

Comment: If for some reason you don't want to modify the current directory, use `-mindepth 1`before `-maxdepth 1`.

Answer (score 6):

If the directory itself shares the same ownership as its files (hidden or not), then you can `chown` it recursively instead. The `-R` option will include hidden files when recursing inside the current directory.

```
$ chown user:group . -R # Will include all hidden files
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, the question specifies that *only* hidden directories are desired to be chowned, whereas this chowns everything.

Comment: @ChrisDown Yes, but since the question and most answers provide code including both files and directories, I thought it'd still be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

I'd think you could use `ls -A` instead, specifically:

```
chown -R username:groupname $(ls -A | grep '^\.')
```

This does what you'd expect `.*` to do, match all files in the current directory that begin with a `.`, excluding `.` and `..`.  *But note this won't behave identically to a bash glob if you need it to match funky file names, like files with spaces in them.*

Comment: `.*` would work with files with funky names.

Comment: @Gilles not unless you did `".*"` or some other escaping.  As is, the command in the question would also fail to properly handle filenames with spaces and the like, my answer just does the same.

Comment: No, `".*"` would pass the two-character string `.*` to the command. `.*` (unquoted) expands to the list of file names starting with a `.`, no matter what characters the file names contain. I'm not sure what your misapprehension here is; keep in mind that a command line is not a string but a list of strings, and a wildcard pattern expands to the list of matches, not to their concatenation with spaces in between or something (it's commands like `echo` that do a concatenation with spaces as separator).

Comment: Withdrawn, clearly I'm confused :)  That's what I get for answering questions on my phone.

Comment: Anything which involves `mycommand $(ls)` is a bad idea. This syntax leads to  unexpected results for lots of characters like: space, semi-column and many more. `find /path/to/dir -print0 | xargs -0 mycommand` or `mycommand *`  (where `*` is a glob expression) are you friends.

Comment: @FranklinPiat good advice, thanks. The `$(ls)` syntax is easy to remember and *usually* works, so I'll leave my answer here, but caveats definitely apply.

Answer (score 0):

A variation of Chris Down solution that filter just hidden directories and removes the -R options. Your original requirement was to change ownership and group classification of hidden directories, not their content.

```
find /home/username -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '.*' -exec chown user:group {} +
```