# Why doesn't "rm -rf ./" delete anything?

Tags: shell, rm

The command `rm -rf ./` does not do anything in a directory full of sub directories and files. Why so? Isn't `-r` supposed to go recursive?

To add more confusion, it even prints an error message suggesting that it is traversing the directory:

```
rm: refusing to remove ‘.’ or ‘..’ directory: skipping ‘./’
```

Comment: Try, rm -rf ./*

Comment: The error message suggests exactly the opposite of what you say it does.

Comment: Very relevant (duplicate?): [Does 'rm .\*' ever delete the parent directory?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90073)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `rm` command refuses to delete the directory by the '.' name. If you instead use the full path name it should delete the directory recursively, i.e. `` rm -rf `pwd`‌ ``.

It is also possible to delete the directory if it is the current directory.

```
[testuser@testhost] /tmp$ mkdir ff

[testuser@testhost] /tmp$ cd ff

[testuser@testhost] /tmp/ff$ touch a b c

[testuser@testhost] /tmp/ff$ rm -rf ./
rm: cannot remove directory: ‘./’

[testuser@testhost] /tmp/ff$ ls
a  b  c

[testuser@testhost] /tmp/ff$ rm -rf /tmp/ff

[testuser@testhost] /tmp/ff$ ls

[testuser@testhost] /tmp/ff$ ls ../ff
ls: cannot access ../ff: No such file or directory

[testuser@testhost] /tmp/ff$ cd ..

[testuser@testhost] /tmp$ ls ff
ls: cannot access ff: No such file or directory
```

From `info rm`:

Any attempt to remove a file whose last file name component is `.' or` ..' is rejected without any prompting.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot remove the current directory because then the current directory would become invalid.

First, change out of the directory you want to remove (e.g. `cd ..`) and then remove the desired directory using its full or relative pathname *from outside*.

Comment: Appreciate your help, but even though the CWD may not be deleted, why aren't any of the directory files/dirs deleted?

Comment: It's pretty simple. You asked `rm` to do something it cannot do. Not only is `rm` not doing it, but it's telling you why not with an informative error message. To delete a directory (recursively or not), your current working directory should be outside of that directory.

Comment: @celada -- I think howard asked for deleting the contents of the present directory not the present directory.

Comment: @vipinkumar: No. Howard asked for deleting the present directory. *You* suggested an alternative in your comment that deletes the contents of the present directory.

Comment: The message says `skipping`, so, yes, exactly like it says, it skips it and moves on to the next argument (but there was only one argument given, so instead it exits).

Comment: You _can_ delete the current directory. Just not with `rm -rf .`

Comment: @roaima yeah, you're right, that's true. I advised exiting that directory and setting the cwd to something else instead because deleting the current directory leaves you in a weird state (in a directory that does not exist anymore) which could be unintuitive and confusing.