# rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '..'

Tags: rm, error-handling

Why when I try to delete `..` from directory I receive error:

```
rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '..'
```

And before you ask why I want to do this: Just because.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192843/why-doesnt-rm-rf-delete-anything

Comment: I don't want to delete parent directory, I want delete link to it, do some sort of trap, directory where you can in and can't out

Comment: Build your own filesystem that does not have the requirement that every directory contains a link to its parent then.  But even if you did, you could still "get out" with `cd /explicit/path/here`.

Answer (score 8):

That's [a safeguard added to most implementations of `rm` to work around a misfeature of some shells (including POSIX shells) where `rm -rf .*` would recursively remove the content of `.` and `..` as well](/q/90073/) (that was fixed by the Forsyth shell and derivatives (like pdksh), `zsh` and `fish` at  least¹).

You can use the `rm` builtin of `zsh` (a shell that doesn't have that misfeature).

```
zmodload zsh/files # to load and enable the builtin version of rm
                   # and a few other utilities
rm -rf ..
```

Alternatively, with BSD or GNU `find` or compatible, you can do:

```
find .. -delete
```

Just to be clear, those delete the content (recursively) of the parent directory (including the current working directory).

If you wanted to unlink the `..` entry from the current directory, generally on modern systems, you can't. `.` and `..` are always there as long as the directory that contain them exists and can't be removed. On some filesystems, they're even virtual (are not physical entries in the directory file).

Even if you managed to remove them (for example by using `debugfs` to edit the content of directories by hand), they would be recreated the next time a file system check (`fsck`) is done and some applications (like the `cd` builtin of POSIX shells) even ignore them completely (`cd ..` shaves one path component off the tail of the current working directory as stored in `$PWD` regardless of whether there's a `..` file in the current directory or not), and POSIX requires `..` in pathname arguments given to system calls to mean the parent directory regardless of whether an actual directory entry exists by that name in the current (or *corresponding* for paths like `dir/../whatever`) directory.

---

<sup>¹ In version 5.2, `bash` added a `globskipdots` option to fix that.</sup>

Comment: "find .. -delete" doesn't work. Deleted everything in my working directory.

Comment: @LucianoDourado, that works exactly as specified. See: *Just to be clear, those delete the content (recursively) of the parent directory (including the current working directory).*

Comment: Yeah, that actually was misuse from my part. But it does excludes everything on the parent directory, although I intended to delete only the hidden files/directories.

Answer (score 0):

I think the command you want is: `rm -rf *`
I think that `rm -rf .*` works on hidden files too? Not sure.

But MAKE SURE you are in the current directory you want to run this from. In other words, type `pwd` or `echo $PWD` to make sure....

So yep, that will remove all files within the current directory.

I am also certain `rm -rf ../*` will work, since I have tested that. You can add as many parent directories ("../") as you wish to that.

So basically, just add a "splat" on the end to bypass the stupid security.

Comment: This does not _describe why_ the error message in the title occurs when trying to remove `..`, which is what the user asks about.