# Why can't I `rm -r .`?

Tags: shell, rm

A question I already asked myself a few times is why I can't delete the current working directory using `rm -r .`

The shell does not have a problem with a non-existing directory as working directory, so I just created an alias for `rm -r "../$(basename "$(pwd)")"`.

Why is there a difference between these two `rm`s, while the output of `realpath .` and `realpath "../$(basename "$(pwd)")"` does not differ and the cwd of the `rm` is also the same?

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but the answer is applicable here. Thanks for the link. But who downvotes here?!

Comment: I don't know, never downvote a duplicated question, just voting to close it.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [Does 'rm .*' ever delete the parent directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90073/does-rm-ever-delete-the-parent-directory/90075#90075) the following part of the POSIX spec applies:

> If either of the files dot or dot-dot are specified as the basename
>   portion of an operand (that is, the final pathname component) or if an
>   operand resolves to the root directory, rm shall write a diagnostic
>   message to standard error and do nothing more with such operands.