# Does `ps` provide the working directory of each process?

Tags: ps, pgrep

Is it correct that the output of `jobs` contains the working directory when invoking each job (not necessarily the current working directory of each job)?

```
$ jobs -l | grep JDBC
[15]  20422 Running   PDFXCview all.pdf &  (wd: ~/mydata/dirlinks/cs/SQL/API/JDBC/general/official/tutorials)
[20]  20542 Running   PDFXCview all.pdf &  (wd: ~/mydata/dirlinks/cs/SQL/API/JDBC/general/wikipedia)
```

Similarly, in `ps`, is it possible to get the previous working directory of each process when invoking it

In `pgrep`, is it possible to search in the pathname (string) of the previous working directory of each process when invoking it,  like `pgrep ...  <pattern_in_working_dir_pathname>`?

I would like to search for processes, by keywords in their working directories when invoking them

Thanks.

Comment: Jobs shows the directory that a jobs was started in. Not its current working directory. try `(cd ~/Downloads; sleep 100) & cd /; jobs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The working directories of processes are knowable by other processes in many operating systems.  They are queryable from the kernel in the BSDs and on Linux, using `sysctl()` and `procfs` respectively.  However, neither the Linux `ps` command from procps nor the `ps` commands in the BSDs obtain and report this information.

To obtain the current directory of a process on the BSDs, the command is `fstat`, which reports the filesystem and i-node number.

```
% fstat -p $$|awk '{ if ("wd" == $4 || 1 == NR) print; }'
USER     CMD          PID   FD MOUNT      INUM MODE         SZ|DV R/W
JdeBP    zsh        71512   wd /usr/home/JdeBP      4 drwxr-xr-x     127  r
%
```

Note that, of course, working directories can be reached by multiple names and those names can vary as things are renamed and links are created/destroyed.  The stable part of them is the file object, the vnode, not the directory entries for reaching it.

So the Linux mechanism, that reports one name in `/proc/pid/cwd`, is not necessarily reliable.

Finally: note that the *current* directory of a process is not necessarily the working directory that it had when the process was spawned, which is all that job control shells *actually* know.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434437/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413225/5132

Comment: Thanks. Does `wd:` part in the output of `job -l` specify the working directory when invoking a job, or the current working directory of the job?

Comment: I already told you the answer to that.

Comment: Can you demonstrate or provide reference?

Comment: I guess that Linux doesn't have a utility `fstat`, correct?

Answer (score 3):

The `jobs` command *may* show working directory the program *started* in, if that directory is different to the shell's current one.  That's because the shell is tracking what it knows (where the process started), not the current state.

It's also dependent on the shell.

eg with `bash`

```
bash-4.4$ cd /tmp
bash-4.4$ sleep 1000 &
[1] 24807
bash-4.4$ jobs -l
[1]+ 24807 Running                 sleep 1000 &
bash-4.4$ cd /
bash-4.4$ jobs -l
[1]+ 24807 Running                 sleep 1000 &  (wd: /tmp)
```

But `ksh93` doesn't do that

```
$ sleep 1000 &
[1]     7164
$ jobs -l
[1] + 7164       Running                 sleep 1000 &
$ cd /
$ jobs -l
[1] + 7164       Running                 sleep 1000 &
$
```

I don't believe there's any portable way of finding the cwd of a process.  `fstat`, `pwdx` and similar may help.  You may need `root` privileges to look at processes you don't own.

On Linux, the processes matching a specific path may be used by looking at the `/proc/.../cwd` symlink:

eg to find processes with `/tmp` in the path:

```
% sudo ls -l /proc/*/cwd | grep /tmp
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 sweh     sweh     0 Jul 28 09:38 /proc/23435/cwd -> /news/tmp
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 sweh     sweh     0 Jul 28 09:39 /proc/7124/cwd -> /news/tmp
```

Remember this may not match the process's internal representation of the directory because of symlinks:

```
$ cd /usr/tmp
$ pwd
/usr/tmp
$ ls -l /proc/self/cwd
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 sweh sweh 0 Jul 28 09:41 /proc/self/cwd -> /var/tmp/
$ ls -l /usr/tmp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 May 13 09:39 /usr/tmp -> ../var/tmp/
$
```

Here the shell thinks I'm in `/usr/tmp` but really it's `/var/tmp`.

EDIT TO ADD:

There is a special case of this problem, where the question might be "what processes are using a mount point".  This isn't reporting the `cwd` but any files that may be open.

So, for example:

```
$ sudo fuser -u -c /brick
/brick:               3552(root)
$ ps -p 3552
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3552 ?        00:04:51 glusterfsd
$
```

We know the `glusterfsd` process is the only one using the `/brick` filesystem

Comment: Thanks. What does the mount point used by a process mean? What is the different of a mount point and working directory of a process?

Comment: If you have `/home` as a mounted filesystem then something using `/home/mylogin/foo/bar` will be using the `/home` mountpoint.  This could be cwd or an open file.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a portable way to do this with `ps` but you can use a for loop with `ps` to print all of the processes and then pipe it to another command to print their current working directories.

Let's start with `pwdx` which specifically prints the current working directory of a process.

Running as root:

```
for i in $(ps aux | awk '{print $2}'); do pwdx $i; done
```

`ps aux | awk '{print $2}'` prints the pid for each process.

`pwdx $i` Passes the i variable which is the pid's to `pwdx`

You can use `pwdx` on a pid itself but the for loop does them all together.

You can also use `lsof` but you may need to install the `lsof` package first depending on your system. Running as root:

```
for i in $(ps aux | awk '{print $2}'); do lsof -p $i | grep cwd; done
```

`ps aux | awk '{print $2}'` prints the PID for each process.

`lsof -p $i` Passes the i variable to `lsof`

`grep cwd` Prints the lines containing `cwd` or the current working directory.

In regards to the `pgrep` command, you can use it in the form of:

```
pgrep <process-name>
```

in order too find the pid of a process but you'll still have to pass it to either `lsof` or `pwdx` to find the current working directory.

The first `for loop` works with Fedora 28, Centos 7.5, RHEL 7.5, and Debian 9 but not FreeBSD 11.

The second `for loop` works with Fedora 28, Centos 7.5, RHEL 7.5, and Debian 9. It also works with FreeBSD 11.1 although in my case, it prints out warning messages regarding the `lsof` version being for FreeBSD 11 while mine is FreeBSD 11.1

Comment: What Unix are you running `ps aux` on? On OpenBSD and Ubuntu, `ps aux` does not show working directory.

Comment: @Kusalananda I was out last night when I posted my answer and wasn't able to test it. As a result, it seems that I forgot and I left off a part of it the command *smacks head*. Adding `ww` will make the columns wider and show as many columns as possible and adding `f` shows the hierarchy of the process. The questionner didn't specify which Unix/distro he's using and while I can't test it with every single one, I have confirmed that ps auxww works with CentOS 7.5, RHEL 7.5, Debian 9, and FreeBSD 11 although `ps auxf` doesn't show the hierarchy in FreeBSD 11.

Comment: @NasirRiley - `ps auxww` does not show the cwd on CentOS 7.5.  `ww` stops `ps` from truncating output, which is useful for long process arguments, or when used with `e` (show environment) but doesn't otherwise add data.  Compare `ps auxe` with `ps auxwwe`.  But even that doesn't show current directory.  eg `$ ps auxwwe | grep httpd | tail -1
apache   29709  0.0  0.1 414980  7676 ?        S    Jul22   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND`  - there's no directory listed for that apache process.

Comment: @StephenHarris You are correct. I thought that by working directory that he meant where the command was running from. There isn't a portable way to do it with `ps` on its own so I've updated my answer.

Comment: `lsof -d cwd` seems to do the trick