# Does `wd:` in `jobs` show the current working directory of each job, or the previous working directory when invoking each job?

Tags: bash, job-control

Does `wd:` in `jobs` show

- the current working directory of each job, or
- the previous working directory when invoking each job?

Can you demonstrate it or quote from some references?

I was under the impression of the second one when asking [Does `ps` provide the working directory of each process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458977/does-ps-provide-the-working-directory-of-each-process), but the replies seem all about the first one.

Comment: I actually explicitly told Tim the answer to this, at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/459033/5132 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jobs prints the working directory the shell had when starting the related job.

What later happens is not in the scope of the shell.

Comment: Thanks. Can you demonstrate it or quote from some references?

Comment: Check the last function in the file sh/xec.c from the Bourne Shell in schilytools.