# Best way to prefix output of a command and check its return value

Tags: bash

is there a better way than the following code to prefix the output of a command but still being able to check its return value?

```
command > "$tmpfile" 2>&1
ret=$?
sed 's/^/  | /' "$tmpfile"
if [[ ! "$ret" -eq 0 ]]; then
    rm "$tmpfile"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Does this help? [Get exit status of process that's piped to another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another)

Comment: don't know what you mean with prefix but your solution to save exit code is fine. for one-liners another common method is cmd `&&` sed `||` rm (but this won't work for exit 1)

Comment: the existing answer using `ret=${PIPESTATUS[0]}` is perfectly complete and obviates the need for a temp file altogether, but I'll just add that if you do use a temp file, the better way to remove it is via a `trap`, e.g., `trap `rm -f "$tmpfile"` EXIT` https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480330/temporary-folder-that-automatically-destroyed-after-process-exit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get exit status of process that's piped to another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `bash` and a few other shells, you can use the `pipefail` option, which when enabled causes the exit status of a pipeline to be that of the rightmost component that failed as opposed to the rightmost component:

```
(set -o pipefail; cmd | sed 's/^/  | /') || exit
```

Another option is to redirect stdout to a process substitution instead of using a pipe:

```
cmd > >(sed 's/^/  | /') || exit
```

Though beware that `sed` which in that case is started in background and is not waited for, may not have finished writing by the time the next command is run.

Specific to `bash`, there's the `$PIPESTATUS` special array (zsh has a `$pipestatus` equivalent) which records the exit status of every component in a pipeline:

```
cmd | sed 's/^/  | /'; ret=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
[ "$ret" -eq 0 ] || exit "$ret"
```

POSIXly, you can  do:

```
{
  ret=$(
    exec 4>&1
    {
      cmd 3>&- 4>&-
      echo "$?" >&4
    } | sed 's/^/  | /' >&3 3>&- 4>&-
  )
} 3>&1
[ "$ret" -eq 0 ] || exit "$ret"
```

You could use a helper function:

```
prefix() (
  prefix=$1; shift
  exit "$(
    exec 4>&1
    { 
      "$@" 3>&- 4>&-
      echo "$?" >&4 3>&- 4>&-
    } | PREFIX=$prefix awk '{print ENVIRON["PREFIX"] $0}' >&3 3>&- 4>&-
  )"
) 3>&1

prefix '  | ' cmd
```

(here switching to `awk` so as to be able to use arbitrary prefixes.

Comment: The pipefail option is exaclty what I needed, thanks! Now  I can do `if command | sed...`