# Trying to remove current directory using rmdir

Tags: ubuntu, directory, directory-structure, mkdir, pwd

I created a directory `dir` at Desktop and then i keyed in `cd dir` so as to make `dir` as my current directory and then i typed in the terminal `rmdir /home/user_name/Desktop/dir` from the `dir` directory itself, and surprisingly this removed the `dir` directory but when i checked my current working directory using `pwd` it was still showing that i am in the `dir` directory,So my question is that how it is possible that i am working in a directory that has already been deleted.i am currently working on Ubuntu

Comment: Try and create a file in that directory and you will see it doesn't actually exist.  Also if you do `ls -la` you will notice that `.` and `..` no longer exist.  I'm not sure what you expected to happen but to me this doesn't seem like an issue at all.  Do you want it to kick you back a directory?  Automagically move you to your home directory?  Complain that you can't delete a directory that you are currently working from?  I don't think any of those would be better or worse than the current behavior.

Comment: my issue is that `rmdir` is simply deleting a directory(on which i am currently working) and it does not even give a error,you are absolutely right that no new file or directory can be made through this directory now but still on using `pwd`  it is still showing a directory that actually do not exist in the file system

Comment: What are you suggesting _should_ have happened?  `rmdir` will only complain if the directory is non-empty.  It's akin to deleting a file form the filesystem that a program is currently reading from or writing to.  No issues.

Comment: All of this, including the behaviour of `pwd`, is already covered at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434417/ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to understand *why* this is, you need to understand the difference between files and inodes. rm, rmdir and mv all take action on the inodes describing the file/directory, not the actual file.  If you have a file/dir open (e.g. by being in the directory), the inode information is removed, but the actual data file associated with the file/dir is not removed until all file handles pointing to it are closed.  So, when you "cd .." the filesystem can swoop in and remove the directory and all its contents.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Inodes.html

Comment: that is the exact explanation that i wanted ,thank you so much