# why we get shell-init: error retrieving current director when using egrep

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, grep

we want to exclude some names from variable

```
# echo $names
abba begiz altonzon music aolala


# echo $names | grep -o '[^[:space:]]\+'
abba
begiz
altonzon
music
aolala
```

when we use `egrep` in order to exclude the two names

then we get exception about :`"shell-init: error retrieving current directory:"`

```
#  echo $names | grep -o '[^[:space:]]\+' | egrep -iv "abba|begiz"
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
altonzon
music
aolala
```

how to avoid this exception?

Comment: Is any of the involved commands an alias or a shell function? Does the error message occur every time?

Comment: you can test it on your Linux  machines , and yes its always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`egrep` is a shell script in some systems, and at least the shells in Debian don't like starting in a removed directory:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/z
$ cd /tmp/z
$ rm -r /tmp/z
$ egrep
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

That's with Bash as `/bin/sh`, Dash gives `sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory`

Use `grep -E` directly to bypass running that shell script, or don't run in a deleted directory.

Related: [What happens when the current directory is deleted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434417/what-happens-when-the-current-directory-is-deleted/434437#434437)

---

A completely different matter is that there's probably some better way to do what you're doing, one that doesn't suffer from problems with [word splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and globbing.

In Bash, you could use arrays:

```
names=(abba begiz altonzon music aolala)
newnames=()
for x in "${names[@]}"; do
    if [[ ! $x =~ ^(abba|begiz)$ ]]; then
        newnames+=("$x")
    fi
done
# do something with newnames
```

Comment: The same scenario as at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434437/5132 indeed.

Comment: @JdeBP, yep, thank you