# ls displays no files even though folder contains files

Tags: ls, cd-command, inode, stat

This question is actually derived from a problem I have with a python library which deletes a file tree and then recreates the content, but on attempt of execution of a file inside the directory, the compiler throws `no such file or directory` error, and I was able to recreate the same situation on *nix systems as such with shell itself.

Shell 1 >

```
mkdir test
cd test
touch a.txt b.txt
```

Shell 2 >

```
rm -rf ~/test
mkdir test
cd test
touch c.txt
```

Shell 1 >

```
ls
```

At this instance, `ls` command on the first shell wont return anything, even though c.txt exists at that particular path.

On reading of some random resources on internet, I stumbled across `stat` command, and I executed it on both shells to check if theres an inode difference and it seems like there is, but I am not sure how can I get to the newly created folder from the first shell without `cd`-ing to it. I am hoping that I can replicate the same process on python.

Thanks in advance for the solutions and ideas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens when the current directory is deleted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434417/what-happens-when-the-current-directory-is-deleted)