# Is it possible to delete . and ..?

Tags: linux, filesystems

Is it possible to delete `.` and `..`?

I read somewhere there are some patches for the linux kernel which let you do that. I have no idea where I read it and I don't know how to search for it because google and duckduckgo ignore the `.`s.

Comment: Are you asking for a specific reason, i.e. do you have an application case where you would actually want/need to do that?

Comment: I am asking out of curiosity.

Comment: Why would you do this? Do you know that `..` refers to the parent directory, and `.` to the current directory?

Comment: Do you want to remove actual directories ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/289385/108618))? or *entries* in some directory only? To see the difference: suppose you're in `/foo/bar/` and you manage to remove `.`. It may be you remove `/foo/bar/`; or it may be `/foo/bar/` still exists but there is no longer `.` *in it*.

Comment: I know what `.` and `.` refer to. I wan't to remove `.` and `..` in the directory not the directory itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, it is possible; for example, on an ext4 file system in `e2test.img`:

```
$ sudo mount e2test.img /mnt/temp
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/temp/dir{1,2}
$ sudo umount /mnt/temp
$ debugfs -w e2test.img
debugfs 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
debugfs:  unlink dir1/..
debugfs:  unlink dir1/.
debugfs:  quit
$ sudo mount e2test.img /mnt/temp
$ ls -a /mnt/temp/dir{1,2}
/mnt/temp/dir1:

/mnt/temp/dir2:
.  ..
```

The shell isn’t particularly confused:

```
$ cd /mnt/temp/dir1
$ pwd
/mnt/temp/dir1
$ cd ..
$ pwd
/mnt/temp
```

As might be expected, `e2fsck` isn’t happy about this:

```
$ e2fsck e2test.img
e2fsck 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Missing '.' in directory inode 113793.
Fix<y>? yes
Setting filetype for entry '.' in ... (113793) to 2.
Missing '..' in directory inode 113793.
Fix<y>? yes
Setting filetype for entry '..' in ... (113793) to 2.
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
'..' in /dir1 (113793) is <The NULL inode> (0), should be / (2).
Fix<y>? yes
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

e2test.img: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
e2test.img: 14/128016 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 18478/512000 blocks
```

The exact behaviour will depend on the specific file system being used. Some don’t even store `.` and `..` entries, but emulate them instead (POSIX requires `.` and `..` to be understood and resolve to the appropriate directories, but doesn’t require them to be physically present).

Comment: POSIX doesn't require them. It requires `.` to resolve to the current directory and `..` to resolve to the parent, but not `readdir()` to include any of them in its result. Actually, the world would be a better place if `readdir()` no longer returned them. See also: https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1228

Comment: @Stéphane yes, I only wanted to explain why a file system would emulate them; thanks for the clarification, I’ve updated the answer.

Comment: I don't think it's good to conflate the emulation of `.` and `..` when resolving paths (which is required by POSIX compat and is done by the kernel at VFS level) and their emulation of `.` and `..` when listing directories (which is done by most filesystems, though not required by POSIX, and not at all useful or reliable). If you re-created `.` as a named pipe or regular file in `debugfs`, `stat .` would still show it as a directory. A much better question IMHO would've been: what programs would *break* if filesystems no longer faked the `.` and `..` entries when listing directories?

Comment: In the (unlikely) case someone actually tries that, notice that `debugfs` is a very blunt tool: `mknod /dir/pipe p` will not create a named pipe inside the `/dir` directory, but one named `/dir/pipe` (yes, including the slashes as part of the filename) inside the current directory.