# difference copy contents folder between /. and /* in linux

Tags: linux, shell

to copy contents from a folder i've read , the use is:

```
cp -rfva ../foldersource/. ./
```

but this works too

```
cp -rfva ../foldersource/* ./
```

is there any difference?

by example if i want to delete  a content from a folder with . :

```
rm -rf ../foldersource/.
```

i get the error:

```
rm:  rejet delete folder '.' or '..':
```

but with asterisk is ok

```
rm -rf ../foldersource/*
```

so, asterisk is better options that works anywhere ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a fundamental difference between these two argument forms. And it's an important one to understand what is happening.

With `../foldersource/.` the argument is passed unchanged to the command, whether it's `cp` or `rm` or something else. It's up to the command whether that trailing dot has special or unique semantics different from the standard Unix convention of simply pointing to the directory it resides in; both `rm` and `cp` seem to treat it as a special case.

With `../foldersource/*` the argument is first expanded by the shell *before* the command is ever even executed and passed any arguments. Thus, `rm` never sees `../foldersource/*`; it sees the expanded version `../foldersource/file1.ext ../foldersource/file2.ext ../foldersource/childfolder1` and so on. This is important because operating systems limit how many arguments can be passed to a command, usually only a few hundred.

Comment: `It's up to the command whether that trailing dot makes any sense` Um, the dot always links to the containing directory itself, so `../foldersource/.` shouldn't be any different from stating `./foldersource/` and in fact its just a redundant way to state  the same thing. No command tries to "make sense" of dot or double dot, since these are standard on Linux/Unix filesystems. `rm` simply rejects removing current working directory as `jimmij` stated in their answer. Also, note that you are using `./` in all of your examples while OP has `../` there. Somewhat of a (big) difference.

Comment: "cp -rfva ../foldersource/. ./ " is equivalent to  "cp -rfva ../foldersource ./", i want to copy foldersource content, but not the folder root

Comment: @Stackdave no, `cp -rfva ../foldersource/. ./` [is NOT equivalent to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228637/100397) `cp -rfva ../foldersource ./`. The trailing `/.` is significant

Comment: While what this answer says is correct, it's missing a very important difference as mentioned in @roaima's answer: the /* variant does not (usually) copy files or directories beginning with .

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy You are right; the `.` is a standard convention in Unix to denote the current directly. Also, thank you for pointing out that I had used `./` in my examples when I should have used `../`; I will fix that. You are incorrect about about whether commands "make sense" of the trailing dot; as the OP points out (and I have experienced with `cp`) both `rm` and `cp` behave differently when a trailing `.` is present. I should have written something like "it's up to the command if the trailing dot has special or unique semantics". I'll change my answer for clarity.

Answer (score 10):

When you copy using `cp -a source/* target/` you are copying most of the files and directories from `source` to `target`. Specifically, the items that are excluded will probably be files beginning with a dot (`.`) in the top level of `source`.

Consider these files (or directories) in `source`

```
apple        # will be copied
banana/      # will be copied, as will all its contents
.cherry      # will not be copied
```

When you copy using `cp -a source/. target/` you are copying the entire contents of `source`, including any items beginning with a dot (`.`) to `target`

Consider these files (or directories) in `source`

```
apple        # will be copied
banana/      # will be copied, as will all its contents
.cherry      # will be copied
```

If you're using `bash`, `zsh`, you can use the [`dotglob` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) to change the meaning of `*` so that it includes files and directories beginning with a dot (`yash` also has a `dotglob` option; however, it then includes `.` and `..` in glob expansions which limits its usability. See also `FIGNORE='@(.|..)'` in `ksh93`).

Interestingly, `cp -a source/. target/` is guaranteed *never* to create the component `target/source`. (On the other hand, `cp -a source target/` will do one of two things depending on whether or not `target` already exists. See [How to copy a folder recursively in an idempotent way using cp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228597/how-to-copy-a-folder-recursively-in-an-idempotent-way-using-cp) for the details.)

---

When you delete using `rm -rf source/*` you are deleting the files and directories within `source` that do not begin with a dot (`.`). Subject to the `dotglob` setting I've already mentioned. It will not delete the directory `source` itself.

When you try to delete using `rm -rf source/.` it will fail - as [others have already explained](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90075/100397) - because POSIX prohibits deletion of a path whose last component is `.` or `..`. The closest equivalent is `rm -rf source`, which will delete the `source` directory and all its contents regardless of whether or not they begin with a dot (`.`).

Comment: See also [Does 'rm .\*' ever delete the parent directory?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/90073) about _`rm -rf .` failing_.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot do `rm -rf ../foldersource/.` because `rm` doesn't allow this, as explicitly stated in the manual:

> Any attempt to remove a file whose last file name component is ‘.’ or ‘..’ is rejected without any prompting, as mandated by POSIX.

and in the POSIX manual `man 1p rm` we see:

> If  either  of  the files dot or dot-dot are specified as the basename
>   portion of an
>          operand (that is, the final pathname component) or if an  operand  resolves  to  the
>          root directory, rm shall write a diagnostic message to standard error and do nothing
>          more with such operands.